# CompilerOptions: NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure, nosuchmethoderror

Anybody got any Idea why this error appears?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Z)V
    at com.google.common.collect.Lists.computeArrayListCapacity(Lists.java:105)
    at com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList(Lists.java:98)
    at com.google.javascript.jscomp.ComposeWarningsGuard.<init>    (ComposeWarningsGuard.java:83)
    at com.google.javascript.jscomp.CompilerOptions.<init>(CompilerOptions.java:791)
```

Code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;

import com.google.javascript.jscomp.CompilationLevel;
import com.google.javascript.jscomp.CompilerOptions;
import com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler;
import com.google.javascript.jscomp.SourceFile;

public class MyJavaScriptCompressor {

    private Compiler cloJsCompressor;

    public MyJavaScriptCompressor() {
    }

    public String closureCompress(File source) {
        CompilerOptions opt = new CompilerOptions();
        int mode = 1;
        CompilationLevel.SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS.setOptionsForCompilationLevel( opt );

        Compiler.setLoggingLevel(Level.OFF);
        cloJsCompressor = new Compiler();
        cloJsCompressor.disableThreads();

        List<SourceFile> externs = Collections.emptyList();
        List<SourceFile> inputs = Arrays.asList(SourceFile.fromFile(source));

        cloJsCompressor.compile( externs, inputs, opt );

        return cloJsCompressor.toSource();
    }
}
```

build path includes

```
compiler.jar
jsoup.jar
yuicompressor.jar
```

how can i get rid of it?!

---

edit:

the error appears in this line:

```
CompilerOptions opt = new CompilerOptions();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved..

.classpath in the project root of eclipse was missing that line:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/compiler.jar"/>
```

i dont know -why- eclipse was not able to fix that automatically..